# JavaScript Programming for ATM

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and I have an assignment to write a javascript program for an ATM with the functions of deposit, withdraw, get balance, transfer-in and transfer-out. The program for the first three functions was given, and I just have to add the transfer-in and transfer-out functions into the given program. I have tried by just adding the two functions to it. It works, but for the transfer-out function, it should verify the receiver account no. (also the account info as done) before doing the transaction. I'm not sure how to do the verification on the receiver account no. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Trial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>$ Trial $</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        verify();

        function Bank(bankName, bankCode){
            this.bankName = bankName;
            this.bankCode = bankCode;

            this.accounts = [];
            this.registerAccount = function(accountInfo){
                this.accounts.push({info: accountInfo, balance: 0});
            }
        }

        function ATM(initCurrency){
            this.currency = initCurrency;
            this.banks = [];

            this.registerBank = function(bank){
                this.banks.push(bank);
            }

            this.auth = function(authinfo){
                return {
                    authinfo: authinfo,
                    operations:[],
                    
                    deposit: function(amount){
                        this.operations.push({type: 'deposit', amount: amount});
                    },

                    withdraw: function(amount){
                        this.operations.push({type: 'withdraw', amount: amount});
                    },

                    transferin: function(amount){
                        this.operations.push({type: 'transfer-in', amount: amount});
                    },

                    getBalance: function(){
                        this.operations.push({type: 'balance-view'});
                    },
                }
            }

            this.transferReg = function(reginfo){
                return {
                    reginfo: reginfo,
                    operations:[],

                    transferout: function(amount){
                        this.operations.push({type: 'transfer-out', amount: amount});
                    },
                }
            }

            this.currencyLeft = function()
            {
                return (this.currency);
            }

            this.commit = function(transaction){
                var account = this.findAccount(transaction.authinfo) && this.regTransferAccount(transaction.reginfo);
                if(account === null){
                    return {status: 'FAILURE'}
                }
                var result = {status: 'SUCCESS'}
                var commitedOperations = []

                for (let operation of transaction.operations){
                    commitedOperations.push(operation);
                    switch (operation.type){
                        case 'deposit':
                            account.balance += operation.amount;
                            this.currency += operation.amount;
                            break;
                        case 'withdraw':
                            account.balance -= operation.amount;
                            this.currency -= operation.amount;
                            break;
                        case 'transfer-in':
                            account.balance += operation.amount;
                            this.currency += operation.amount;
                            break;
                        case 'transfer-out':
                            account.balance -= operation.amount;
                            this.currency -= operation.amount;
                            break;
                        case 'balance-view':
                            result.data = account.balance;
                            break;
                    }
                    if(account.balance < 0 || this.currency < 0){
                        result.status = 'FAILURE';
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(result.status === 'FAILURE'){
                    while(commitedOperations.length){
                        let undoOperation = commitedOperations.pop();
                        switch(undoOperation.type){
                        case 'deposit':
                            account.balance -= undoOperation.amount;
                            this.currency -= undoOperation.amount;
                            break;
                        case 'withdraw':
                            account.balance += undoOperation.amount;
                            this.currency += undoOperation.amount;
                            break;
                        case 'transfer-in':
                            amount.balance -= undoOperation.amount;
                            this.currency -= undoOperation.amount;
                            break;
                        case 'transfer-out':
                            account.balance += undoOperation.amount;
                            this.currency += undoOperation.amount;
                            break;
                        case 'balance-view':
                            delete result.data;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }

            this.findAccount = function(authinfo){
                var bank = this.banks.reduce(function(acc, cur){
                    return (cur.bankCode === authinfo.bankCode) ? cur : acc
                }, null);

                return bank ? bank.accounts.reduce(function(acc, cur){
                    return(cur.info.code === authinfo.code && cur.info.password === authinfo.password) ? cur : acc
                }, null) : null
            }

            this.regTransferAccount = function(reginfo){
                var bank = this.banks.reduce(function(acc, cur){
                    return (cur.bankCode === reginfo.bankCode) ? cur : acc
                }, null);

                return bank ? bank.accounts.reduce(function(acc, cur){
                    return(cur.info.code === reginfo.code && cur.info.password === reginfo.password && cur.info.receiverAccNo === reginfo.receiverAccNo) ? cur : acc
                }, null) : null
            }
        }

        function verify(){
            var bankName = 'Standard Chartered';
            var bankCode = 52;
            var bank = new Bank(bankName, bankCode);

            var accountInfo = {
                name: 'John',
                code: 113322,
                password: 223333,

                receiverName: 'Thomas',
                receiverAccNo: 1234567,
            }
            bank.registerAccount(accountInfo);

            var initCurrency = 1000
            var atm = new ATM(initCurrency);
            atm.registerBank(bank);

            {
                let transaction = atm.auth({bankCode: 52, code: 113322, password: 223333});
                transaction.getBalance();
                let result = atm.commit(transaction);
                console.log(result.status === 'SUCCESS');
                console.log(result.data === 0);
            }

            {
                let transaction = atm.auth({bankCode: 52, code: 113322, password: 223333});
                transaction.deposit(5600);
                transaction.getBalance();
                let result = atm.commit(transaction);
                console.log(result.status === 'SUCCESS');
                console.log(result.data === 5600);
            }

            {
                let transaction = atm.auth({bankCode: 52, code: 113322, password: 223333});
                transaction.withdraw(3000);
                transaction.getBalance();
                let result = atm.commit(transaction);
                console.log(result.status === 'SUCCESS');
                console.log(result.data === 2600);
            }

            {
                let transaction = atm.auth({bankCode: 52, code: 113322, password: 223333});
                transaction.transferin(2000);
                transaction.getBalance();
                let result = atm.commit(transaction);
                console.log(result.status === 'SUCCESS');
                console.log(result.data === 4600);
            }

            {
                let transaction = atm.transferReg({bankCode: 52, code: 113322, password: 223333, receiverAccNo: 123456789});
                transaction.transferout(2000);
                transaction.getBalance();
                let result = atm.commit(transaction);
                console.log(result.status === 'SUCCESS');
                console.log(result.data === 2600);
            }

            console.log(atm.currencyLeft() === 3600);

            {
                let transaction = atm.auth({bankCode: 52, code: 113322, password: 2233});
                transaction.withdraw(3000);
                transaction.getBalance();
                let result = atm.commit(transaction);
                console.log(result.status === 'FAILURE');
                console.log(result.data === undefined);
            }

            {
                let transaction = atm.auth({bankCode: 52, code: 113322, password: 223333});
                transaction.withdraw(1000);
                transaction.withdraw(1000);
                transaction.withdraw(1000);
                transaction.withdraw(1000);
                transaction.withdraw(1000);
                transaction.withdraw(1000);
                transaction.withdraw(1000);
                transaction.getBalance();
                let result = atm.commit(transaction);
                console.log(result.status === 'FAILURE');
                console.log(result.data === undefined);
            }

            {
                let transaction = atm.transferReg({bankCode: 52, code: 113322, password: 2233, receiverAccNo: 123456789});
                transaction.transferout(3000);
                transaction.getBalance();
                let result = atm.commit(transaction);
                console.log(result.status === 'FAILURE');
                console.log(result.data === undefined);
            }

            {
                let transaction = atm.transferReg({bankCode: 52, code: 113322, password: 223333, receiverAccNo: 987654321});
                transaction.transferout(3000);
                transaction.getBalance();
                let result = atm.commit(transaction);
                console.log(result.status === 'FAILURE');
                console.log(result.data === undefined);
            }

            {
                let transaction = atm.transferReg({bankCode: 52, code: 113322, password: 223333, receiverAccNo: 123456789});
                transaction.transferout(1000);
                transaction.transferout(1000);
                transaction.transferout(1000);
                transaction.transferout(1000);
                transaction.transferout(1000);
                transaction.transferout(1000);
                transaction.transferout(1000);
                transaction.getBalance();
                let result = atm.commit(transaction);
                console.log(result.status === 'FAILURE');
                console.log(result.data === undefined);
            }

            {
                let transaction = atm.auth({bankCode: 52, code: 113322, password: 223333});
                transaction.getBalance();
                let result = atm.commit(transaction);
                console.log(result.status === 'SUCCESS');
                console.log(result.data === 2600);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your solution is fine: all tests output `true`. As far as I can see, the `commit` function performs the verification you talk about.

Comment: Yes, but I need to verify one more property (the receiver account no.) for the transfer-out function. I don't know how to write at all so I haven't added the codes there.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code with the name receiver. Can you be concrete?

Comment: As shown in the edited program code above.